# Boto3 AWS find who has access to a type resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I am trying to find out who has access to a resource. I tried going through the IAM access analyzer and created an analyzer, but it only shows specific findings. Is there a way to use IAM Access Analyzer, via boto3, to query who/which roles have access?

Comment: You can check cloudtrial logs to see which IAM user/role invoked a given api. But I don't think it has any info about whether it was boto3 or not.

Comment: I am just trying to find a way to find who has access to a resource, cloudtrail could tell me who invoked that permission but it wouldn't tell me who can access permission.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to review IAM policies and find those that reference a specific resource, then enumerate the users, groups, and roles with that policy? And the boto3 part of it is irrelevant. Or do you genuinely want to find those policies that have conditions on user agent being boto3?

Comment: I am trying to find IAM policies that have resource references to enumerate users, groups, and roles using that policy, but my goal is to do it programatically.

Comment: Do you have any sample code to show? Also the policy you are trying to find is a managed policy? Not inline policy?

Comment: I have the code to pull the role names and get the policies documents for the roles. The policy attached could be either managed policy or inline policy.